# How can I hash a string to a bigint in presto?

Tags: hash, presto, varbinary, trino

I have a long string and I would like to semi-uniquely represent it as a bigint.  Ideally I'd just take the hash, but [presto hash functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html) seem to want to return "varbinary", and I can't find a function to convert a varbinary into a bigint.

If I write:

`cast(xxhash64(cast('asdf' as varbinary)) as bigint)`

I get an error saying I can't cast a varbinary to a bigint.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`from_big_endian_64`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html?highlight=big_endian#from_big_endian_64) to convert a 64-bit binary value to a `bigint`:

```
presto> SELECT from_big_endian_64(xxhash64(CAST('asdf' AS varbinary)));

        _col0
---------------------
 4708639809588864798
(1 row)
```